# Mysql find mode of columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query that returns the mode of a column. However in my case i need to return the mode of 12 columns in a table

Running this query for each column is way too inefficient and it takes quite long.

Is there any way to improve on this query such that in one query it returns the mode of all 12 columns?

My query is as below

```
SELECT {$type} as mode_value, COUNT({$type}) AS mode 
                                    FROM alterations
                                    GROUP BY   {$type} 
                                    ORDER BY mode DESC 
                                    LIMIT 1
```

Where $type is the column name

I am using codeigniter as my framework

Comment: No, there's no way around that unless you want to maintain another "aggregator" table...

Comment: If this is running slow you should add an index to all sane values of $type

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select modeval, count(*) mode from
(select col1 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col2 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col3 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col4 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col5 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col6 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col7 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col8 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col9 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col10 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col11 modeval FROM alterations union all
 select col12 modeval FROM alterations) sq
GROUP BY modeval ORDER BY mode DESC LIMIT 1
```